# Is the FCC National Broadband Map API endpoint working?

Tags: python, python-requests, get

I have been troubleshooting the FCC National Broadband Map API connection for some time and I believe that the endpoint that is listed in the [BDC Public Data API Specifications](https://us-fcc.app.box.com/v/bdc-public-data-api-spec) is unavailable/broken/down. I am unable to receive any response (success or fail) when I make a call to that endpoint.

I used the following code to make the GET request:

```
import requests

#API Base URL
base_url = "https://broadbandmap.fcc.gov/api/public/map"

#User Credentials
username = "username@domain.com"
with open("token.txt", "r") as file: #token.txt contains hash_value from FCC Website
    hash_value = file.read().strip()

#3.1 View list of "As Of Dates"
list_as_of_dates_url = f"{base_url}/listAsOfDates"
print(list_as_of_dates_url)
list_as_of_dates_headers = {"username":username, "hash_value":hash_value}
print("Making GET request to provided URL")
list_as_of_dates_response = requests.get(list_as_of_dates_url, headers=list_as_of_dates_headers)
print("GET Request complete.")
print('3.1 View List of "As Of Dates" Response: ', list_as_of_dates_response.json())
```

The script never prints "GET Request complete" because it hangs indefinitely during the GET request. Output:

I also tried pasting `list_as_of_dates_url` into my browser’s URL line and manually adding my the “username” and “hash_value” key-value pairs into the browser’s network console headers section. When I do that, I receive the following errors:

```
“Refused to connect to 'https://broadbandmap.fcc.gov/api/public/map/listAsOfDates' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src  'none'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.”

“Refused to connect to 'https://broadbandmap.fcc.gov/api/public/map/listAsOfDates' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.”
```

The API Specification does not include any mention of setting connect-src.

Furthermore, when using the Data Download Portal on the website to manually download data, the Base Request URL is “https://broadbandmap.fcc.gov/nbm/map/api/”. I’ve tried editing my API Request URL to match the base URL for the GUI download with no avail.

Has anyone successfully used the National Broadband Map API? If so, what endpoint URL did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run across this issue a couple of times, and it comes down to one of two things, both relating to filtering.

Situation 1:

If you are trying to access the site from AWS I have not been able to get it to work in any way. I have a ticket open with the FCC on this issue right now and will report back if I hear any thing.

Situation 2:

If you are working from a local machine there appears to be some kind of filtering in place. The easiest way around that I have found is to modify the user-agent to a different string. Here is some sample code that I have used and is working well:

```py
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.clear()
s.headers.update({'username': 'a@b.co'})
s.headers.update({'hash_value': '*redacted*'})
s.headers.update({'user-agent': 'play/0.0.0'})
url = "https://broadbandmap.fcc.gov/api/public/map/listAsOfDates"
r = s.get(url, timeout=5)
```

There are some more code snippets on my work Github as well at: [npappin-wsu/caiAnalysis](https://github.com/npappin-wsu/caiAnalysis)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked. Thanks! May I ask how you determined there was filtering going on? 

Also, for the sake of sharing, I just want to note that I was able to get the API Request to work as intended when I made the call using JavaScript, rather than Python, so this seems to be a language-specific issue.

Comment: Really just a lot of persistence, a little luck, and a few friends from a discord that is working on BDC data. That does make a little sense as it would be more difficult to filter a JavaScript engine out from a browser.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Nick Pappin. Manually overwriting the 'user-agent' header worked for me on 3.1 (List as of dates) and 3.2 (View list of availability data). When I try to make a call on 3.4 (Download Files) using the same approach, I receive a 403 error. Have you successfully downloaded data from the API using 3.4? Do I need to get special access to download data? I see on your GitHub that you're using "nbm/map/api/getNBMDataDownloadFile/" for downloads. Is there a reason you're using that instead of "api/public/map"?

Comment: I am working on this (3.4 endpoint) right now and should have an update by the end of the day. As for the usage of the "getNBMDataDownloadFile" that was because it pre-dated the api specification and authentication. As an aside AWS is now working and you should be able to download/upload things just fine!